# Adding buttons using gridlayout

Tags: java, swing, jpanel, jbutton, grid-layout

I'm trying to create a simple tic tac toe board made by 9x9 JButtons.
I used a 2d array and a gridlayout but the result is nothing, a frame without any button.
What I'm doing wrong?

```
import java.awt.GridLayout;
import javax.swing.*;


public class Main extends JFrame
{
    private JPanel panel;
    private JButton[][]buttons;
    private final int SIZE = 9;
    private GridLayout experimentLayout;
    public Main()
    {
        super("Tic Tac Toe");
        setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        setSize(500,500);
        setResizable(false);
        setLocationRelativeTo(null);

        experimentLayout =  new GridLayout(SIZE,SIZE);

        panel = new JPanel();
        panel.setLayout(experimentLayout);


        buttons = new JButton[SIZE][SIZE];
        addButtons();


        add(panel);
        setVisible(true);
    }
    public void addButtons()
    {
        for(int k=0;k<SIZE;k++)
            for(int j=0;j<SIZE;j++)
            {
                buttons[k][j] = new JButton(k+1+", "+(j+1));
                experimentLayout.addLayoutComponent("testName", buttons[k][j]);
            }

    }


    public static void main(String[] args) 
    {
        new Main();

    }

}
```

The addButton method is adding the buttons to the array and straight after to the panel.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You need to add the buttons to your `JPanel`:

```
public void addButtons(JPanel panel) {
   for (int k = 0; k < SIZE; k++) {
      for (int j = 0; j < SIZE; j++) {
         buttons[k][j] = new JButton(k + 1 + ", " + (j + 1));
         panel.add(buttons[k][j]);
      }
   }
}
```

Answer (score 4):

```
// add buttons to the panel INSTEAD of the layout
// experimentLayout.addLayoutComponent("testName", buttons[k][j]);
panel.add(buttons[k][j]);
```

Further advice:

1. Don't extend `JFrame`, just keep a reference to one as long as needed.  Only extend frame when adding or changing functionality..
2. Instead of `setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);` use `setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.DISPOSE_ON_CLOSE);` as seen in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7143398/418556).
3. Instead of `setSize(500,500);` use `panel.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(500,500));`.  Or better still, extend `JButton` to make a `SquareButton` that returns a preferred size equal to the largest preferred of width or height.  The last will ensure the GUI is the size it needs to be, square & allowing enough space to show the text.
4. Instead of `setLocationRelativeTo(null);` use `setLocationByPlatform(true);` as seen in the answer linked in point 2.
5. Add `pack()` before `setVisible(true);` which ensures the GUI is the size it needs to be, to display the content.
6. Instead of `setResizable(false)` call `setMinimumSize(getSize())`.
7. Start & update the GUI on the EDT.  See [Concurrency in Swing](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/concurrency/) for more details.

Comment: Thank you so much for those advices! I always confused between setsize and preferredsize and the other things you mentioned and I didn't know what to use. thanks again!